# Meteor JS: Iron Router Refresh Function

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I couldn't find anything regarding this topic. What I am trying to do is when the user refreshes the page, iron router reroutes the user to a different template.

Something along the lines of

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function(){
  //If(refresh) reroute to home template
  //Else this.next()
});
```

Does iron router have anything that does the functionality?

Thank you for your time,
LL

Comment: This sounds like a question that stems from a problem with a better solution then what you're initially looking for. Refreshing a page is basically loading a page, again. What are you trying to accomplish that would require the same page to suddenly load differently just because of how it was loaded?

Comment: I have a multiple step form (3 pages in total). All the data is stored in session vars until all the forms have been completed. So if the user refreshes mid form all the data will be lost and the form will need to reset. You may be right in that my structure could be reworked. Eventually I will probably combine all the form pages into one page, but for now this is one of the solutions I was looking at.

Comment: Check if your session is set in the created callback `Template['myTemplate'].onCreated = function(){}` and `Router.go(...)` where you need to be if not set. That would be my approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the idea below9k! Here is what I went with.

In my first form template:

```
Template.form1.onRendered(function(){
  Session.set('formState', true);
})
```

In iron router function:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function(){
  if(Session.get('formState')){
    this.next();
  }else{
    Router.go('form1');
  }
  },
  {only: ['form2', 'form3']}
);
```

Thanks again for the answer! Works like a charm.

LL